# Is today's Israel/Palestine dynamic unique?

Tags: territorial-dispute, genocide, land

We currently have a situation in the Middle East in which both parties fighting for a piece of land have committed some truly atrocious actions, but more powerful nations and coalitions are waffling on what the best path forward should be.

It really seems like both parties have done actions that can't be easily swept under the rug, and that to remove one party from the Gaza Strip demonstrates tacit approval of the party left behind.

Can anyone think of any historical situation comparable to the current situation we're facing, in which:

1. Both belligerents have publicly broken the 'rules' of war as defined for the era.
2. There are larger powers that are not close allies with either of the parties in question but have a vested interest in the stability of the region.
3. They have implemented some sort of countermeasure against both parties in order to create a forced peace.

Comment: This seems to be a question about history, and not about contemporary politics. I will migrate it to History Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Philipp I have altered the question to more explicitly refer to contemporary politics.

Comment: It's still a question for experts in history, not a question for experts in politics. If you want a competent answer, then I would recommend you [fix the version on history stack exchange](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/72610/has-there-ever-been-an-instance-of-a-larger-country-saying-neither-of-you-get-i) and ask for it to be reopened, not the version here.

Comment: @Philipp I respectfully disagree. If the vote to reopen doesn't pass, I'll drop the matter entirely.

Comment: TBH, easy answer: Yugoslavia. (Also, like in this case, some sides there broke the rules more than others...) Of course, some might say that Germany etc. were closer to some of the former Yugoslav countries than others... I'm not too sure if these kind of analogy questions work too well here though.

Comment: BTW, some in Germany are asking now similar questions to what were raised during the Yugoslav wars https://www.rferl.org/a/russia-ukraine-hamas-israel-interview-lange/32635953.html